# How to prevent selectOneRadio to be preset on default boolean value?

Tags: spring, jsf, radio-button

I currently have a simple spring app, with a simple page, backed with a simple bean.  Here's the relevant snippet from the page...

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="q1" value="#{controller.formBean.question1}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="true" itemLabel="Yes"  />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="false" itemLabel="No"  />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

And from the backing bean, formBean:

```
private boolean question1;
public void setQuestion1(boolean question1) {
    this.question1 = question1;
}
public boolean isQuestion1() {
    return question1;
}
```

And the controller instantiates the bean (verified not null).

But that's part of the problem, since booleans when initialized default to false, this form control always has a "default answer" of "No" pre-selected.   I'd like to have the user explicitly select yes or no, so I need to make sure the radio button isn't prepopulated.

I tried converting all the fields to Boolean (so I could represent true/false/null) but spring collapsed and wanted booleans not Booleans.

Anyone have any ideas?  I'm new to Spring, and i'm sure i'm missing something really simple here.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Boolean` instead of `boolean`. The `Boolean` has a third "state": `null`. I'm not sure what you mean with "spring collapsed" when you tried it.

A more cleaner alternative is to use an `enum` instead.

```
public enum Choice {
    Yes, No;
}

public Choice[] getChoices() {
    return Choice.values();
}
```

with

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="q1" value="#{controller.formBean.question1}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{data.choices}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

and use

```
private Choice question1;
```

Comment: I mentioned I already tried using Boolean.  Upon loading the page I got fatal errors that I unfortunately did not save...  IIRC it had a NPE.  My peers have odd views about enums and I dont think i'll be able to get away with using one.... Any insight on the Boolean?